# How to implement Facebook to my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I am used Facebook for my application where I have to post comment on wallpaper. But now I have to modify that application. I want page after user login it will give option like

1. post to wall
2. retrieve friends
3. logout

Can we implement this page after login instead of direct opening the page of post wall.

If yes then provide me  some code with brief details. Even your previous code help me lot to solve my previous problem

Thanks

Comment: Next time onward i reply your answer but kindly  help me to find this answer

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I correctly understand your question, but if you are looking for an easy way to post comments and images to a wall or also to retrieve friends etc ... go check out [BMSocialShare](https://github.com/blockhaus/BMSocialShare) - currently better use the dev branch though! In case you want to share to many other platforms as well try [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/).